# Trying to fetch a div from another website

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the data from the recent donations div on this website: http://umcgames.buycraft.net/
the div does not have an ID but it does have a header defined. Would realy appreciate help on this, been looking for a way all day ;)

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: Trying to get the complete html of the class=content div that is located directly under <div class="header">Recent donations</div>

Comment: you will need to parse the html with this http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

you can use the class of the div (content) 
like this 
$('.content').eq(3).val();

Comment: @IdanMagled I would post that as an answer, that actually is a legit idea.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to parse the html with this [this php class](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) 
you can use the class of the div (content) like this: `$('.content').eq(3).val();`
this site using jquery as i seen.

Comment: thanks, will see if I can get this to work, eq(3) refers to 3rd instance of the word content I believe then?

Comment: third instance of the class contant.
i checked that in the console, its working.
if it works hit the V sign :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
<?php
$html=file_get_contents('http://umcgames.buycraft.net/');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$rec_d=0;
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $tag) {

    if ($tag->nodeValue === 'Recent donations') {
        $rec_d=1;
    }
    if($rec_d==1 && $tag->getAttribute('class') ==='content' )
    {
        foreach($tag->getElementsByTagName('p') as $ptag)
        {
        echo $ptag->nodeValue; // to get the content in between of tags...
        $rec_d=0;
        }
    }
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
No recent payments to display.
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked untill I added a payment which changed the contents to a series of other divs. Already changed 'p' to div but this only shows the text without linebreaks or formatting.